# How to test for an element in an array of arrays with chai and mocha?

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I have an array with arrays nested in it.  I tried to test it with Chai, but it doesn't pass the test.  I have checked that the value in both of these arrays are correct.

```
const mainArray = [
  ['f', 'r', 'e', 'e'], ['b', 'e', 'e']
]
const targetArray = ['b', 'e', 'e']

expect(mainArray).to.include(targetArray) //False, expect it to be True
```

How can I test this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.deep.members`

```
chai.expect(mainArray).to.include.deep.members([targetArray])
```

When doing `.to.include(targetArray)`, its looking in the `mainArray` to have the members in `targetArray`. So its looking for `b`, `e` inside `mainArray`